# How to modify header wso2

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I am creating a POC . I am trying to send "Authorization : Bearer  "  to a webservice proxy .
How can i do this using Class Mediation in WSO2ESB .

And also how can i modify the old payload by adding the new payload .... with in class Mediation

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
<property name="Authorization" value="Bearer" scope="transport"/>
```

Changing the payload can be done in a number of ways, one way to change the whole payload is using the payloadFactory.

```
<payloadFactory>
    <format>
        <m:getquote xmlns:m="http://services.samples">
            <m:request>
                <m:symbol>$1</m:symbol>
            </m:request>
        </m:getquote>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="//m0:Code" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Or the same can be achieved with the enrich mediator:

```
<enrich>
    <source type="inline" clone="false">
        <m:getquote xmlns:m="http://services.samples">
            <m:request>
                <m:symbol>$1</m:symbol>
            </m:request>
        </m:getquote>
    </source>
    <target type="body" action="replace" />
</enrich>
<enrich>
    <source type="property" clone="true" property="PATIENTS"/>
    <target xmlns:m="http://services.samples" xpath="//m:symbol"/>
</enrich>
```

Hope this helps

Regards, nidkil